# what's assembly for Microsoft.Web.Service3 of .NET 2.0 in .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

Microsoft has Web Services Enhancements (WSE) 3.0 for .NET. The assembly is  Micresoft.Web.Service3.dll. What's the replacement for this in .NET 4.0?

Comment: You need to start moving to WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSE 3.0 was the last version of WSE.  In later .Net framework versions, WSE was superseded by WCF (Windows Communications Foundation).  There is info on how to migrate from WSE to WCF [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732008.aspx).  WCF support for WS-* specifications is detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730294.aspx).